# CSS overlapping elements by preserving parent size

Tags: css, position, absolute, overlapping

I want to overlap some elements without using `position: absolute`. The reason therefore is that I have several vertical sections (which should not overlap) containing elements which overlap. The problem is, I cannot know beforehand whether the overlapping or the overlapped element has the bigger size.
If one of those would receive a `position: absolute` it would be taken out of flow and therefore the parent container would not be sized accordingly and the sections would overlap.
I have already found this question but nobody seemed to answer the question.
Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nNhtU/

Comment: give `height` for your `imagesize` and add `overflow:scroll`

Comment: if I dont know the `imagesize` because the images are added via CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's ok to use jQuery, this can be done quite easily. Set the `overflow` property of the parent element to `scroll`:

```
.designer-question {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

And then you can set the height of each `.designer-question` to the height of its `img` using a simple `each` loop:

```
$('.designer-question').each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);                   // Get jQuery of each designer question
    var $backImg = $('.back img', $el);  // Get background image
    $el.css('height', $backImg.height());
});
```

I've applied this to your jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jfdPb/1/

Comment: I wanted to do it with CSS and therefore I told the designer to size the background bigger than the overlapping stuff.